# php define() confusing due to return value in function remaining the same

Tags: php

Hi my limited understanding of PHP the define() function redefines a variable to another correct?
So in the following function if the pointer to $default=='on' surely the return value would be true? Instead Im still getting 'on' returned. Thanks for forgiving my limited knowledge.

```
function isseter(&$default,&$reserve=NULL)
{
define('on',true,true);define('off',false,true); 

if (isset($default)) return $default;
else return $reserve;
}
```

Comment: define() defines a constant, it does nothing to the effect of "redefining a variable". I suggest you read the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: I actually did go php.net before I asked and it looked like if I provided eg $default='on'; then $default would be true. Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`define` doesn't *redefine* a *variable*. It *defines* a *constant*.

Basically, you could do something like

```
define('on', 'It is on');
```

which defines a constant `on` that you can use in the rest of your program, like this:

```
echo on // Output will be "It is on"
```

Notice that there is no dollar sign in front of the on since it is not a variable

You can modify your program to make it work like you want like this.

```
function isseter(&$default,&$reserve=NULL)
{
    define('on',true,true);

    if (isset($default)) return $default == on
    else return $reserve;
}
```

This returns the boolean result of comparing the variable `$default` to the constant `on`, which is true. Although, once you define a constant, it is enabled for the rest of your program and not just inside that function. So usually you define constants in the beginning of your program. You can do this:

```
// Constants
define('on',true,true);

// Functions
function isseter(&$default,&$reserve=NULL)
{
    if (isset($default)) return $default == on
    else return $reserve;
}

// Rest of program
```